# $n|(a-a´)+(b-b´)$, n divisible by the sum of two divisible numbers.

Tags: group-theory

> **Proposition**: Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a,a´,b,b´\in\mathbb{Z}$.
>   If $a_n=a´_n$ and b_n=b´_n, so
>
> $(a+b)_n=(a´+b´)_n$.

**Proof:**

$a_n=a´_n\implies n|a-a´\\b_n=b´_n\implies n|b-b´\\$

therefore $n|(a-a´)+(b-b´)\implies n|(a+b)-(a´+b´)\implies (a+b)_n=(a´+b´)_n $

**Question:**

I do not understand one step of the derivation. How can $n|(a-a´)+(b-b´)$ be true? I know that if $a_n=a´_n$, then $n$ is multiple  (or divisible) by $(a-a´)$. But if I sum another number who is a multiple the summation may not be a multiple. For example: $15$ is divisible by $3$ and by $5$, however it is not divisible by $3+5=8.$ How do I know $n$ is divisible by $(a-a´)+(b-b´)$?

*I am assuming the terminology used is standard. If someone has any doubt on that regard. Please leave a comment.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is $a_n$ defined? $n\mid (a+b)$ does not mean that $n$ is divisible by $(a+b)$, be careful. The tag "group theory" is inappropriate. It should be "elementary number theory".

Comment: @DietrichBurde                 What does it mean then?

Comment: It means that $(a+b)$ is divisible by $n$, and not that $n$ is divisible by $(a+b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n \mid (a-a')$ means that $a-a' = nk$, and similarly: $n \mid (b-b')$ which gives $b-b' = nl$. So $(a+b)-(a'+b') = (a-a')+(b-b') = nk+nl = n(k+l) = ns$. Thus $ n \mid (a+b) - (a'+b')$, and of course $n \mid (a-a') + (b-b')$.